# Laravel Route error Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have been trying to get a simple example to work but it keeps giving me Route [login] not defined when I try to load the page. I have tried to test each part individually with no luck; what could be the issue here?

My code is as follows:

Class:Users.php

```
  class users extends Model
{
   public $table = 'users';
}
```

Controller:UserController.php

```
use App\users;
public function index()
{
    return "Hello Laravel";

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/user','UserController@index');
```

Comment: u r having only *createUser* route, but why u are accessing *login* route

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` to see if route is defined

Comment: Have you defined the login route??

Comment: I am not trying to access login at all if you read my code you will see that I am only trying to save data to a database at this point but the page does not load gives login not defined while i am not using login in my code?

Comment: @It is all yours,  it seems that the route is not being defined what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the controller itself still unsure as to what the issue was but deleting and recreating the controller seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

clear route cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

after that you can check your routes to be sure:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Remember - apparently you cannot use route caching if you have ANY route closures. Make a controller and use your logic there and direct your route to the Controller/Method.

Proper route defining example
:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
```

Comment: Route cache cleared but get **LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.**

Comment: Apparently you cannot use route caching if you have ANY route closures. Make a controller and use your logic there and direct your route to the Controller/Method. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7319#issuecomment-73362932

Comment: Thanks for the help Adam, my logic is already in a controller as seen above

Comment: was my response the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not issue still persists I have added the file name for more info.

Comment: Defining route: Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');

Comment: Updated code still error persists, controller seems to be the issue recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

try this  `Auth::routes();` before your code

```
Route::get('/user','UserController@index');
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

see if the route is defined in web.php and if it has a name like this

Route::get('/example', 'ExampleController@index')->name('example');

in your view you can use the helper route('example');

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#introduction):

> Just run `php artisan make:auth` and `php artisan migrate` in a fresh Laravel application. Then, navigate your browser to
>   http://your-app.test/register or any other URL that is assigned to
>   your application. These two commands will take care of scaffolding
>   your entire authentication system!

Comment: Can you provide more information, like what this command does?